# Piping data to a file with the windows ‘ShellExecute’ function

Tags: windows, delphi, shellexecute

I am using the  ‘**ShellExecute**’ function in windows vista

Is there any way to pipe the output to a file?

i.e.

MySqlDump.exe  '-u user1  -ppassword  dbName  >  TheOutputFile.Sql

Here my code

```
theProgram     :=  'MySqlDump.exe';
itsParameters  :=  '-u user1  -ppassword  dbName';
rslt := ShellExecute(0, 'open',
                       pChar (theProgram),
                       pChar (itsParameters),
                       nil,
                       SW_SHOW);
```

EDIT:

I have tried

```
 itsParameters  :=  '-u user1  -ppassword  dbName > TheOutputFile.Sql';
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Charles, you can use the redirector simbol ">" in a ShellExecute, but using the cmd.exe which is the Windows command interpreter.

try this sample

```
ShellExecute(0,nil,'cmd.exe','/c MySqlDump.exe -u user1  -ppassword  dbName > TheOutputFile.Sql',nil,sw_normal);
```

Another options is use pipes, you can find a very nice example in this [link](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#AppRedirectOutput).

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario the simplest approach (barring a cmd script) is probably to use [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(VS.80).aspx) instead of ShellExecute.

Or better yet use the --result-file option to mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot vouch for the validity of this code or site, but I've heard of [DosCommand.pas](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid49DE08C6F1F50FF2FB9AE972C3D50E60D9C0F63C.aspx?s=socket) more than once. I'll check it tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the process using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) and provide one end of a pipe you create in hStrOutput of the [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(VS.85).aspx) structure. There are [plenty examples online](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&q=delphi+CreateProcess+CreatePipe&aq=f&oq=&aqi=).